# Evolution of partial sum of a sequence of induced Dirichlet characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, characters, sieve-theory

Let's consider the Dirichlet Character $\chi_3(n)$ modulo 3 given by $\chi_3(1)=1$, $\chi_3(2)=-1$ and $\chi_3(3)=\chi_3(0)=0$.

Lets consider the sequence of induced characters $\chi^{P_N} $ obtained from $\chi_3$ having modulo $3.P_1...P_N$ where $P_N$ is the $N$-th prime number.

So at each step to define the new Character we replace by zero the value of multiple of $P_N$, we have :

$\chi_3 = (0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,...)$

$\chi^{P_1} =(0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,...)$ (all multiple of 2 have been put ot zero)

$\chi^{P_3} =(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,...)$ (all multiple of 5 have been put to zero)

So we obtain a sequence of induced characters with increasing modulo. My question is on the behavior of the maximum of the partial sum of the $\chi^{P_N}$ as $N$ increases :

$$S(\chi^{P_N},x) = |\sum_{n=1}^{x} \chi^{P_N}(n)|$$

$$Max_x(S(\chi^{P_N},x)$$

How this maximum will evoluate ?

My feeling is that this maximum will go up and down when $N$ goes to infinity and so that for a fixed constant $M$ (big enough) we can find an infinity of induced characters with this maximum lower than $M$. But is it true ? How to prove this is right or wrong ? Any reference on similar problem or idea ? Sieve theory can solve this kind of problem ?

(I already made a post on the subject in a more general way here : [On partial sum of non-primitive Dirichlet characters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232218/on-partial-sum-of-non-primitive-dirichlet-characters))

Comment: Is "suite" some technical thing, or just the French word for "sequence"?

Comment: Yes, it is French meaning "sequence"  (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suite#French)

Comment: would it be different from taking $\chi_2$ and removing successively the multiples of every odd primes ? and did you find anything with $\displaystyle F_N(s) = \sum_n X^{P_N} (n) n^{-s} = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi^{P_N}(p) p^{-s}}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $\chi_2$ ? the second character of the sequence ? To my knowledge the function $F_N(s)$ (which is noted generally $L(\chi,s)$) is not usefull to estimate character sums but I will think about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are looking at can be stated in terms of the sum
$$
S(x,y):= \sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ P^-(n)>y}} \chi_3(n) ,
$$
where $P^-(n)$ denotes the smallest prime divisor of $n$, with the convention that $P^-(1)=+\infty$. If $y\ge3$, then this sum is $Q$-periodic, where
$$
Q=\prod_{p\le y} p = e^{(1+o(1))y}.
$$
Because the modulus is very smooth, the Polya-Vinogradov bound can be improved quite a bit using the Eratosthenes-Legendre sieve:
$$
S(x,y)= \sum_{n\le x} \chi_3(n) \sum_{d|(n,Q)} \mu(d)
 = \sum_{d|Q} \mu(d)\chi_3(d) \sum_{m\le x/d}\chi_3(m) .
$$
The inner sum is $O(1)$ by the 3-periodicity of $\chi_3$, so that
$$
S(x,y) \ll \sum_{d|Q} 1 = 2^{\pi(y)} = Q^{(\log 2+o(1))/\log\log Q} ,
$$
which is $Q^{o(1)}$ as $y\to\infty$.

It is even possible to go further: note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\le N} \chi_3(n) 
 =\sum_{\substack{k\ge0 \\ 1+3k\le N}} 1 - \sum_{\substack{k\ge0 \\ 2+3k\le N}} 1
 &= \left\lfloor \frac{N-1}{3} \right\rfloor -  \left\lfloor \frac{N-2}{3}
 \right\rfloor \\
 &= \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if $N$ is in $[1,2)$ mod 3},\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases},
\end{align}
so that
$$
S(x,y) = \sum_{d|Q,\, d\in D} \mu(d)\chi_3(d),
$$
where
$$
D := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}} \left( \frac{x}{3n+2}, \frac{x}{3n+1}\right].
$$
This can be now estimated using smooth number technology. In particular, the interesting case is when $x$ is of size $Q$, in which case lattice point count heuristics start becoming accurate. What you could try and use now is either the saddle point method (see Tenenbaum's book "Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory"), or to try and adapt recent work of R. de la Breteche and G. Tenenbaum (see http://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Gerald.Tenenbaum/PUBLIC/Prepublications_et_publications/Psi-resM.pdf.)

Comment: Dear Dimitris thanks for your help, you have shown that the upper bound can be improved, but is there an increasing lower bound ? I am intereseted to find in this sequence of character an infinite number having their $Max|(S(x,y)|$ lower than a fixed constant, do you think it is possible or realistic ? or the $Max$ is converging to infinity ?

Comment: @Koukoulopoulos the only lower bound I found for this sequence of $Max$ is a constant (because the character are induced). For primitive character the $Max$ of partial sum increases with modulus (and lower bound depending on modulus exists) but for induced characters, what can we say ?

Answer (score 0):

By the [Pólya-Vinogradov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_sum), $|S(\chi_N,x)|\ll (p_1\cdots p_N)^{1/2}$, whose order you can estimate using the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: The Pólya-Vinogradov inequality provides an upper bound but does not provide any clue about what the maximum is doing below this bound for N increasing... I did not find any lower bound for this maximum that will increase for N increasing. So it seems (for me) a very hard problem to understand how this maximum behaves when N increases. I would like to show that an infinity of these maximum are lower than a fixed constant and I Wonder if this showing this is as hard as RH !